# Migrate error using Nuxt, Prisma, Supabase

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, prisma, supabase

```
npx prisma migrate status

Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "postgres", schema "public" at "aws-0-ap-southeast-1.pooler.supabase.com:6543"
Error: Schema engine error:
ERROR: prepared statement "s0" does not exist
```

This result should have come out:

```
Your database is now in sync with your schema.
```

Answer (score 0):

When using supavisor you need to add `?pgbouncer=true` on the connection string, as per [this guide](https://supabase.com/partners/integrations/prisma).